# Where is the button to add any other parameters in "Change Signature" window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So. I have a *virtual* method which I want to change. I also need all child methods took all changes. I see the **Remove** button, but I need to **Add** some parameters. As far as I remember, that button also should be here. But I can't see it. I'm using **Visual Studio 2019**.

[image: "Change Signature" window without Add button]

I tried to change the signature of some other methods but that didn't bring any solution, because there was also no the button I needed.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I would echo the request for more information found in [this report to the VS Development team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-find-add-button-in-change-signature-pop-up/1245666).